# Water pressure booster

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure

I need to get a water preasssure booster for my two story home and would like to know what should I look for. I know a specific brand can't be named, so I'm looking in specifications I should look for the pump, like minimum gpm, horsepower, etc...

My water utility sometimes feeds water to my home at less than 10 PSI. Way too low to take a shower upstairs. Their response is basically to get a cistern and water pump, cause sometimes the water is cut off completely.

For now, I'm trying to get a water pump booster to connect my 1/2 inch water pipe. I don't intend to run it all the time since electricity costs are pretty high here and only need it when showering late at night when the pressure is at its lowest. I already have a check valve at the mains so water doesn't go back out. I intend to get a water cistern later on, but for now I'd like to get a booster pump.

Comment: Keep in mind that it will not be useful to just put a pump inline with a low pressure line to boost the output pressure. The reason is that the pump will need an adequate flow of low pressure water to create the high pressure flow. You will need to arrange for a low pressure holding tank so that the pump has the necessary intake volume.

Comment: @MichaelKaras I think your comment describes my answer...

Comment: Where is this? Do you have a tank water heater or a tankless?

Comment: @SolarMike - Indeed. I tried to make the detailed point of why.

Comment: I actually have a solar water heater with 80 gallon on the roof. I understand about the pump running dry.

Comment: Have you contacted the water utility about this? You may qualify for a free service upgrade. In my city under 7psi dynamic flow is considered unsatisfactory and if it's because of the city's line they are obligated to bring it to current standards.

Comment: They basically tell you to get a cistern and pump. It's actually in the regulations.